# arcpy.management.CreateBuildingSceneLayerPackage fails when run outside ArcGIS Pro - ERROR 003266: Absolute Z values used

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, scene-layer-package, ifc

I have an arcpy script that loads a BIM IFC file and then creates a building scene layer package (slpk) with it. It's pretty simple and it works well when running it from the ArcGIS Pro Python console, but it fails when running it from VS Code.

The error that I get is:

> ERROR 003266: Absolute Z values used at the
> CreateBuildingSceneLayerPackage function.

I am using a cloned ArcGIS-Python environment. Any suggestions?

```
arcpy.management.MakeBuildingLayer(
    in_feature_dataset=file_path,
    out_layer=file_name_without_extension
)
arcpy.management.CreateBuildingSceneLayerPackage(
    in_dataset=file_name_without_extension,
    out_slpk=new_slpk,
    out_coor_system=projection_pseudo_mercator,
    transform_method=None,
    texture_optimization="DESKTOP",
    target_cloud_connection=None
)
```